# How to filter out objects separated by commas under one variable in R

Tags: r

So there's a variable in my dataset called date_added, which essentially has dates in it like such:

September 8th, 2019

October 24th, 2014

Anyway, I want to create a new variable that only has the year. On top of that, the dataset classifies these values as characters. Can someone also show me how to filter out the date and also to reclassify it as numeric if that is possible?

Thanks

Edit: I mean filter out EVERY observation to only show the year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate` to convert these values to date and then extract year from it.

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c('September 8th, 2019', 'October 24th, 2014')
date <- mdy(x)
year <- year(date)

date
#[1] "2019-09-08" "2014-10-24"
year
#[1] 2019 2014
```

Comment: What if I wanted to apply this to every observation under the variable?

Comment: @Lucas So if your dataframe is called `df` you could do `df$date <- mdy(df$date_added)` and `df$year <- year(date)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` with `.*,` to remove everything until `,` and then cast the rest using `as.integer` or `as.numeric` to a number.

```
as.integer(sub(".*,", "", c("September 8th, 2019", "October 24th, 2014")))
#[1] 2019 2014
```